# 50 ohm D-dot probe measured with 50 ohm scope

Tags: oscilloscope, probe

I am attempting to measure the signal from a 50 ohm D-dot probe. The manufacturer says to use a 1M ohm scope but I only have a 50 ohm scope. How do I need to set up my tools correctly to receive an accurate measurement? Thank you.

Comment: What kind of oscilloscope do you have that is 50 ohm only?

Comment: Show spec where it specifies 1M load please.

Comment: It seems you are referring to 50 Ohm integrator with a large RC filter , so you need a FET buffer or very fast Op Amp to match the frequency response to drive 50 Ohms